# Husky showing Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yarnpkg, husky

Recently I tried integrating husky on my application for pre-commit formatting. I am only using rubocop to test the commit but it gives out an error when I try to commit.

My package.json

```rb
{
  "name": "asdf",
  "private": true,
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "{app,spec}/**/*.rb": [
      "bin/rubocop --require rubocop-rspec --safe-auto-correct",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.5"
  }
}
```

The error it gives

```
husky > pre-commit (node v8.15.1)
↓ Stashing changes... [skipped]
  → No partially staged files found...
   ❯ Running linters...
     ❯ Running tasks for {app,spec}/**/*.rb
       ✖ bin/rubocop --require rubocop-rspec --safe-auto-correct
        git add

       ✖ bin/rubocop --require rubocop-rspec --safe-auto-correct found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.

       /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:489:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.5.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.0 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

My rvm

```rb
=* ruby-2.5.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.3 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]
```

NOTE: `rails server` runs just fine and so does every other commands.

Comment: My question is I'm getting an error on git commit

Comment: Okay My question is how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Update `ruby` version in your `Gemfile`:

```
ruby "2.5.1"
```

It runs on occasion (because there are not so many differences between `2.5.0` and `2.5.1`) and “runs successfully” basically proves nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that won't change my applications drastically? @Aleksei

Comment: Absolutely sure. You just confirmed it runs perfectly on `2.5.1`, also it’s a minor update that is nevertheless to be applied. Another option would be to downgrade rails version, but I strongly discourage to do that.

Comment: It solved the error but now I'm getting `Incompatible version ` error.

Comment: ``` /home/meerkat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.2/lib/jaro_winkler.rb:6:in `require': incompatible library version - /home/meerkat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.2/lib/jaro_winkler/jaro_winkler_ext.so (LoadError)
 from /home/meerkat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/jaro_winkler-1.5.2/lib/jaro_winkler.rb:6:in  ```

Comment: You have to install the respective ruby version locally `rvm 2.5.1` and re-run `bundle install`.

Comment: I tried `bundle update jaro_winkler` too but it still doesn't work

Comment: You need to rebuild native exceptions of this gem. I have no idea how to achieve it and frankly, I do not see how is it connected to the OP.